# Clickable Form Images Stuck Below Div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have two back and forth arrows that can be clicked to move through photos in a frame on my one-page website. My terminology might not be correct here. The div that holds the photos and the back and forth arrows appears below my screen instead of in the screen scene div. I could move the images up to appear in the screen scene, but not the arrows. Even when I move the arrows, the div stays anchored below the screen, if that makes sense. So when I reduce my screen width, the width of the images scale but the height of the div does not. I would like to have the entire images div appear within the screen scene and scale properly, and to move the arrows to the upper right of the photos, outside the photo frame. Can anyone show me how to fix this?

```js
var images = [
  'squirrel.jpg',
  'ewes.jpg',
];

function slideShowForward() {
  images.push(images.shift());
  document.getElementById('images').style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + images[0] + ')';
}

function slideShowBack() {
  images.unshift(images.pop());
  document.getElementById('images').style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + images[0] + ')';
}
```

```css
/* Portfolio Page
--------------------------------------------- */

#portfolio-page {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh !important;
  float: left;
}

#port-pic-1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh !important;
  float: left;
  background: url("just-grass.jpg") no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  z-index: -5;
}

#port-pic-2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh !important;
  float: left;
  background: url("port-pic-2.jpg") no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  z-index: -5;
}

#grey-block {
  background-color: grey;
  width: 100%;
  height: 67px;
}

#images {
  background-image: url('giraffe.jpg');
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 23%;
  min-width: 200px;
  margin: 8% 0 0 10%;
}

​
```

```html
<div id="portfolio-page">

  <div id="port-pic-1">
    <div id="grey-block"></div>
  </div>

  <div id="images" style="max-width:100%; height:auto;">
    <div class="form">
      <img src="left-arrow.png" onclick="slideShowBack();" style="width: 39px; height: 34px;" />
      <img src="right-arrow.png" onclick="slideShowForward();" style="width: 39px; height: 34px;" />
    </div </div>

  </div>

</div>​
```

Comment: Putting this into jsfiddle would help a lot.

Comment: Hi – sorry, I'm not very good at this! I don't know what a jsfiddle is.

Comment: To everyone who tried to fix this, I can't see where to reply to you except here. Thank you for trying to help but it didn't work and/or I missed where your edits appeared (from this end, couldn't see edits or I missed where they're located).

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ is a site for posting code snippets that you can execute. If you could put your code into this site and save it and paste the link here, it would be easy for us to see your problem and fix it.

Comment: Thanks, Will. I tried the jsfiddle website but only code shows up when I click "Run". I think I don't know enough yet to use StackOverflow or fsfiddle but thank you for replying to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a jsfiddle with your current code: [Original Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/quba4db8/)

**What you are currently doing**

For your current layout, you have tried to use `#port-pic-1 { float: left; }` to remove the block from the page flow so that your `#images` block will be higher up on the page.

**Why this doesn't work**

Block elements (`<div>`) ignore the floating elements and position themselves the way you are hoping, but inline elements (`<img>`) do not. They float around floating elements.

**Possible Fixes**

There are many different ways that you could position your arrow buttons. What I would do is remove the float property, and use absolute position for the buttons.[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/quba4db8/1/)

HTML

```
<div id="portfolio-page">
 <div id="port-pic-1">
   <div id="grey-block"></div>
   <div id="images" style="max-width:100%; height:auto;">
     <div class="form">
       <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="left" onclick="slideShowBack();" style="width: 39px; height: 34px;" />
       <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="right" onclick="slideShowForward();" style="width: 39px; height: 34px;" />
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#port-pic-1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh !important;
  background: url("http://placehold.it/400x400") no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  z-index: -5;
}

#images {
  background-image: url('giraffe.jpg');
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8%;
  left: 10%;
}
```

Comment: Hi Will, thanks for making a jsfiddle and for your explanation about block elements. I substituted your code for what I had, but already my page was so clogged with other stuff from  attempted fixes that nothing was working. Here's a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hh2wxuxf/1/ of what I ended up using (run = ?). In reality, I left the arrows inside the image, added some javascript from the internet, and now have a box of images that lives on the right page but has an enormously long height. Baby steps. Thank you so much for your help and excellent information which I have saved.